# Site deployed on EC2 returning ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when making requests to Node Express Server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to make a request to the my Node Express server via the browser and I am being returned with `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

i.e.

```
POST http://localhost:9000/api/search net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Requests from the Chrome console are also refused.

However, when I make curl requests from the EC2 terminal, the request is successful and i'm returned a JSON.

My `nginx.conf` file is detailed below:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  server_name _;

  location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' *;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' *;
  }

  location /sockjs-node {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }

  location /api {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
  }
}
```

From within the EC2 instance, the firewall status is:

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active
    To                         Action      From
    --                         ------      ----
    OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
    Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
    9000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
    OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
    Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
    9000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

`netstat -tunlp` returns

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 172.31.2.45:68          0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                -
```

My EC2 security group rules look like this

[image: EC2 security group rules]

I've no idea what the issue could be. Any help would be appreciated.

**SOLUTION:** I've managed to resolve the issue by changing all fetch requests on the front-end to use the EC2 IP address instead of localhost. This doesn't seem very optimal though. Is there some sort of wildcard operator I could use instead as the EC2 IP address changes on restart. Any advances would be appreciated!

Comment: Requests in the browser are local for the user and not for the server. So it tries to find `localhost` server on the user's machine

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I see, so what would the solution be? I've tried using the EC2 public IP in the `nginx` config for port 9000 with no luck also.

Comment: You have to set up your backend in such a way that it will be possible to access it from outside

Comment: I'm not quite sure what that means, is there a video or tutorial that could point me in the right direction? I've watched/read quite a few and they all set it up similar to the way I have described above.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:** I've managed to resolve the issue by changing all fetch requests on the front-end to use the EC2 IP address instead of localhost. This doesn't seem very optimal though. Is there some sort of wildcard operator I could use instead as the EC2 IP address changes on restart. Any advances would be appreciated!